# which dependency will be downloaded?

Tags: java, gradle

I have a build script:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
   mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {  
   compile group : 'org.hibernate', name : 'hibernate-core', version :'4.+'
   testCompile group : 'junit', name : 'junit', version: '4.+'
}
```

My question is what exactly version will be downloaded? The latest available version or random? What if some version, satisfies 4.+ restricon are incompatible?

Comment: `For Maven repositories, this is done using the maven-metadata.xml file, while for Ivy repositories this is done by directory listing.` http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html (51.7. How dependency resolution works)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is about downloading, not uploading. `4.+` will resolve to the latest 4.x version. Not sure I understand your other question about compatibility (you'd have to explain in more detail).